# 4bit multiplier in verilog without multiplication operator

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to write a Verilog module that multiplies two 4bit inputs, without using `*` operator, but I get some errors:

```
module multiplier(
            output[7:0] prod,
            input[3:0] a,
            input[3:0] b);

            reg [7:0] result=8'h00;

            always @(*)
            begin
                for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
                begin
                    if((b&(1<<<i))!=0)
                    begin
                        result = result+(a<<<i);
                    end

                end
            end
            assign prod = result;
endmodule
```

Errors:

[Synth 8-2715] syntax error near =

[Synth 8-2715] syntax error near =

[Synth 8-993] result is an unknown type

[Common 17-69] Command failed: Vivado Synthesis failed

---

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT:
I modified the code, now i get:
[Synth 8-1031] i is not declared

Comment: You need to declare integer i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reg [7:0] result=16'h00;
```

Should be

```
reg [7:0] result=8'h00;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module multiplier(
        output[7:0] prod,
        input[3:0] a,
        input[3:0] b);

        reg [7:0] result;
            reg[2:0] i;

        always @(*)
        begin
            result=0;
            for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
                    begin
                if(b[i]==1'b1)
                        begin
                    result = result+(a<<i);
                        end

                    end
        end
        assign prod = result;
endmodule
```

For your code, if I had a = 15 and b = 15, the result would have been 72. You must assign a value for result in always block result=0;